# cname record to rhcloud.Com not working anymore

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, dns-lookup

I have a website hosted at rhcloud.com. I added 2 years ago a cname on my domain name dp-global.vn to redirect to the website (gdp-robertduy.rhcloud.com).
Today it is not working anymore and the website via my domain name is not reachable.
I just checked the dns lookup of my domain name : it resolves to 54.196.200.207
this ip address belongs to amazon (amazonaws) therefore I think rhcloud.com is using amazon cloud.
Would you know what could prevent the cname record to work now ?

Here is the DNS records :

```
dp-global.vn.   0   NS  dns107.ovh.net.         
dp-global.vn.   0   NS  ns107.ovh.net.      
dp-global.vn.   0   MX  1 mx0.ovh.net.  
dp-global.vn.   0   MX  100 mxb.ovh.net.    
webmail.dp-global.vn.   0   A   213.186.33.83   
www.dp-global.vn.   0   A   213.186.33.5    
dp-global.vn.   0   CNAME   gdp-robertduy.rhcloud.com.  
ftp.dp-global.vn.   0   CNAME   ftp.cluster013.ovh.net.     
imap.dp-global.vn.  0   CNAME   ns0.ovh.net.    
mail.dp-global.vn.  0   CNAME   ns0.ovh.net.    
ox.dp-global.vn.    0   CNAME   ox.ovh.net.     
pop3.dp-global.vn.  0   CNAME   ns0.ovh.net.    
smtp.dp-global.vn.  0   CNAME   ns0.ovh.net.    
wm.dp-global.vn.    0   CNAME   ns0.ovh.net.    
www.dp-global.vn.   500 TXT "1|dp-global.vn"    
dp-global.vn.   600 SPF "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all"
```

(www.dp-global.vn redirects to dp-global.vn with OVH redirection)

Thank you

Comment: https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203728154--Naked-Domains-on-OpenShift

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The host is OVH and I contacted them. They confirm that "naked" cname is allowed. Beside, the actual cname record was working fine until the problem appears recently. OVH also say that 54.196.200.207 ip address is not responding correctly. But I don't know what to do with this info because gdp-robertduy.rhcloud.com is working fine independently

Comment: I add that OVH is also the DNS provider

Comment: Can you paste the DNS records of dp-global.vn? I have noticed that dp-global.vn is resolving to 54.196.200.207 which is not responding. gdp-robertduy.rhcloud.com is resolving to some other IP address which is 54.234.64.123. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you run the "host" command on your domain name, you will see that it is not setup as a cname, but rather as an a record

cdaley-redhat cdaley$ host dp-global.vn
dp-global.vn has address 54.234.64.123

Right now i can reach that website without issues, but you should use a cname instead of an ip address in case your gear gets moved to a different node.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. Indeed, this has started working again today. I absolutely don't know what happened. What I see is that dp-global.vn nslookup resolves now to 54.234.64.123, which is the correct ip address.
The host for dns did not give me any explanation yet for this long service breaking.